# using 2 submit buttons in a single form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

i have a form that allows the user to submit the values, it was working fine, but now i have introduced another button in b/w the form "Save as Draft" .

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input name="title">
    <input name="tag1">    
    <textarea name="details"></textarea>

    <button name="draft" type="submit1" class="btn btn-default">Save as Draft</button>
    <input name="location" required>
    /*
    *
    few more i/p values
    *
    */

<button name="save" type="submit" value="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

What i want to do is to save the values of title, tag1 and details in database without saving the values that are under the save as draft button. For this i used the following code

```
if ($_POST['draft'])
    {
        //exectue the required code
    }
elseif($_POST['save'])
    {
        //exectue the required code
    }
```

now the issue is that if i click on save as draft it still checks the codition that is below this button (in this eg i have made the location necessary), whereas the requirement is that if the user clicks on "Save as Draft" then the values should get saved and it should not be necessary to fill other values below it, but if submit button is clicked then it is necessary to fill all values. can anyone  tell how to do so

Comment: You can do the form validation / requirements on the server side. Otherwise you can use JavaScript to skip the validation when that particular button is clicked.

Comment: Can you please add javascript which you are using for the validation

Comment: "it still checks the codition that is below this button" - that's a misconception of how (server)php<->http<->browser<->html(client) works. When the user clicks a button in the browser window, the server-side php instance, that produced the html form code as output, is most likely long,long done and already garbage collected. Because the user clicked a button the browser collects the form data (name=value pairs of _all_ valid controls) and sends a http request to the server which in turn starts a new php instance to run your script from top to bottom, again sending the output back the client

Comment: You should use client validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this using javascript. You will need to put an onclick handler on the Save Draft button that removes the required attribute from any fields that shouldn't be required for that submission. Alternatively, you could remove the required attribute from all fields, and handle form validation with custom javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript.
Please try this code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input name="title" id="title">
    <input name="tag1" id-"tag1">    
    <textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>

    <button name="draft" id="draft" class="btn btn-default" onclick="update_draft()">Save as Draft</button>
    <input name="location" required>
    /*
    *
    few more i/p values
    *
    */

<button name="save" type="submit" value="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

JS :

```
<script>
function update_draft(){

            if($("#title").val() === "")
            {
              alert("empty title");
            }
            else if($("#tag1").val()==="")
            {
              alert("empty tag");
            }
            else if($("#details").val()==="")
            {
              alert("empty details");
            }
            else
            {
                   $.post('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>', {draft:true,title: $("#title").val(), tag1: $("#tag1").val(),details: $("#details").val() }, function(data, status){

                });
            }
}
</script>
```

SERVER SIDE ::

```
if($_POST["draft"]){

}
elseif($_POST["save"]){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input name="title">
    <input name="tag1">    
    <textarea name="details"></textarea>

    <button name="draft" id="draft" type="submit1" class="btn btn-default">Save as Draft</button>
    <input name="location" required>
    /*
    *
    few more i/p values
    *
    */

<button name="save" id="save" type="submit" value="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

```
<script>
    $( "#save" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "I'm Save" );

    });

    $( "#draft" ).submit(function( event ) {
      alert( "I'm Draft" );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `echo var_dump($_POST['draft']);` produces the output `string(0) ""`, which indicates that `$_POST['draft']` is an empty string. In other words, the value is false and the rest of your code doesn't get executed.

You need to use `isset` to check if the key exists. I was able to read which button was pressed using the following simplified code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['draft'])) {
    echo 'Draft was saved';
} else if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo 'Form was submitted';
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

?>
<form method='post'>
<input name='draft' type='submit' value='Save Draft'>
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The following code, which consists of code that you posted, worked for me as well:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['draft'])) {
    echo "Draft was made";
} else if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    echo "Form was saved";
}
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
    <input name="title">
    <input name="tag1">
    <textarea name="details"></textarea>

    <button name="draft" type="submit1" class="btn btn-default">Save as Draft</button>
    <input name="location" required>
    /*
    *
    few more i/p values
    *
    */

<button name="save" type="submit" value="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```